# CSS caption over hover?

Tags: html, css, animation, effect

I have a few div boxes on my page, and I'd like to make them display text when you hover over them. I was looking at a few tutorials but I can't seem to get it to work with mine, here is an example of one of my boxes.

html:

```
  <div class="squar-1">
    <div class="text-1">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.squar-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #e57373;
  float: left;
}

.squar-1 .text-1 {
  position:relative;
  bottom:30px;
  left:0px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.squar-1:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's working, you wrote .text instead of .text-1

```css
.squar-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #e57373;
  float: left;
}

.squar-1 .text-1 {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.squar-1:hover .text-1 {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
  <div class="squar-1">
    <div class="text-1">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: to transition text, you should used opacity instead of visibility like:

```css
.squar-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #e57373;
  float: left;
}

.squar-1 .text-1 {
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.squar-1:hover .text-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="squar-1">
    <div class="text-1">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! Do you know how I could make it fade in as well? I tried `transition-duration: 600ms;` but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I put it in the wrong place? I put it under `.squar-1:hover .text-1 {`